# c# FTDI 24bit two's complement implement

Tags: c#, ftdi

I am a beginner at C# and would like some advice on how to solve the following problem:

My code read 3 byte from ADC true FTDI ic and calculating value. Problem is that sometimes I get values under zero (less than 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000) and my calculating value jump to a big number. I need to implement two's complement but I and I don't know how.

```
byte[] readData1 = new byte[3]; 
ftStatus = myFtdiDevice.Read(readData1, numBytesAvailable, ref numBytesRead); //read data from FTDI
int vrednost1 = (readData1[2] << 16) | (readData1[1] << 8) | (readData1[0]); //convert LSB MSB
int v = ((((4.096 / 16777216) * vrednost1) / 4) * 250); //calculate
```

Comment: Do you have *big endian* or *little endian*? For Instance, what is `readData1` for `300`, please? Is it `{0, 1, 44}` or `{44, 1, 0}`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert the data *left-justified*, so that your sign-bit lands in the spot your PC processor treats as a sign bit.  Then right-shift back, which will automatically perform sign-extension.

```
int left_justified = (readData[2] << 24) | (readData[1] << 16) | (readData[0] << 8);
int result = left_justified >> 8;
```

Equivalently, one can mark the byte containing a sign bit as signed, so the processor will perform sign extension:

```
int result = (unchecked((sbyte)readData[2]) << 16) | (readData[1] << 8) | readData[0];
```

The second approach with a cast only works if the sign bit is already aligned left within any one of the bytes.  The left-justification approach can work for arbitrary sizes, such as 18-bit two's complement readings.  In this situation the cast to `sbyte` wouldn't do the job.

```
int left_justified18 = (readData[2] << 30) | (readData[1] << 22) | (readData[0] << 14);
int result18 = left_justified >> 14;
```

Comment: Thanks, easy solution.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the only obscure moment here is *endianness* (big or little). Assuming that `byte[0]` stands for the *least* significant byte you can put

```
private static int FromInt24(byte[] data) {
  int result = (data[2] << 16) | (data[1] << 8) | data[0];

  return data[2] < 128
    ? result                       // positive number
    : -((~result & 0xFFFFFF) + 1); // negative number, its abs value is 2-complement
}
```

**Demo:**

```
  byte[][] tests = new byte[][] {
    new byte[] { 255, 255, 255},
    new byte[] {   44,  1,   0},
  };

  string report = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, tests
    .Select(test => $"[{string.Join(", ", test.Select(x => $"0x{x:X2}"))}] == {FromInt24(test)}"));

  Console.Write(report);
```

**Outcome:**

```
[0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF] == -1
[0x2C, 0x01, 0x00] == 300
```

If you have *big* endianness (e.g. `300` == `{0, 1, 44}`) you have to *swap* bytes:

```
private static int FromInt24(byte[] data) {
  int result = (data[0] << 16) | (data[1] << 8) | data[2];

  return data[0] < 128
    ? result
    : -((~result & 0xFFFFFF) + 1);
}
```

Comment: Easy way to handle signed data is `((byte[2] << 24) | (byte[1] << 16) || (byte[0] << 8)) >> 8`.  No need for a manual sign-extension step when the right-shift operator does it for you.

Comment: And I think you mean *endianness* not *ending*

Comment: @ Ben Voigt: Thank you! You are quite right your computation is better in case this `Int24` has the same endianness as `Int32`. Another reason for using `?` is to demonstrate OP how to compute 2-complement

Comment: @mrkefca: Something like `int mrkefca = FromInt24(readData1);`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko: Left-justification is possible with either endianness of course, for big endian it would be : `((data[0] << 24) | (data[1] << 16) | (data[2] << 8)) >> 8`

Comment: And yet another approach would be `(((sbyte)data[0]) << 16) | (data[1] << 8) | (data[2])`.  The key is to make the computer see the correct bit as a sign bit.